# How to get background color of SVG converted properly into Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, svg

Im converting a d3 svg object with use of canvg library to an canvas and display it as an image (png).

The resulting image has a transparent background, which is not what I want. I need this with a white background.

So i tried to set the background color of svg element. When viewing svg element it is fine, but the converted image is still transparent.
I also tried, to alter background of the canvas object, but this is also not working.

first approach (svg):

```
var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg").attr("style","background: white;")...
```

second aproach (canvas):

```
canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), $("#chart").html());

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.style.background = 'white';
var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.write('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
```

Does anyone know, on which object I have to set the background color, in order to get it converted properly in png image ?

Edit: With the information mentioned in ThisOneGuys answers, I found this solution.

```
var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg") ...

svg.append("rect")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%")
.attr("fill", "white");
```

With the appended rect, I get what I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran in to this before. As you know the CSS doesn't pass get put in the DOM, so it's not read by the conversion. So you have to do inline styling instead. But the way you are currently doing it is incorrect.

So instead of using :

```
.attr("style","background: white;").
```

You have to set the style like this :

```
.style('fill', 'white');
```

That should work fine :)

Comment: this doesnt give me the correct background color, instead my axis label text is now white. but background is still transparent in converted image

Comment: hmm. The problem is definitely in the styling on the svg and not the canvas. Have you got some other styling conflicting with it somewhere where you have looked over ?

Comment: could you set up a simple fiddle with your problem ? I can check it out myself then :)

Comment: If you look at this link : https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html Go down to styling. You will notice you can't have the background styling on svg.But you can have fill like I mentioned. Have a read that may help

Comment: I'll accept your answer, as it lead me to a solution. Im updating my question with the answer

Comment: Setting `fill` on the `<svg>` node will just make all its children default to this fill instead of black. That has nothing to do with the background-color !

Answer (score 4):

To append a `<rect>` is one solution, an other solution is to render the background color after you've called `canvg' method.

You can call every drawing operations from the canvas API to draw on your rasterized version so, it's possible to fill the background using `ctx.fillRect`. To make the new drawings appear in the background, you just have to set the `globalCompositeOperation` property to `destination-over`.

```js
var $container = $('#svg-container'),
      content = $container.html().trim(),
      canvas = document.getElementById('svg-canvas');

     // Since we will edit the canvas afterward, we need to remove that #!~$^ default mouseEvent listener
    canvg(canvas, content, {ignoreMouse: true});
     // now you've rendered your svg, you can draw the background on the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

     // all drawings will be made behind the already painted pixels
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'
      // set the color
    ctx.fillStyle = $container.find('svg').css('background-color');
     // draw the background
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


    var theImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    $('#svg-img').attr('src', theImage);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
<section>
  <header>
    <h1>SVG:</h1>
  </header>
  <div id='svg-container'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <circle cx="60" cy="70" r=50 style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <header>
    <h1>Canvas:</h1>
  </header>
  <canvas id="svg-canvas"></canvas>
</section>
<section>
  <header>
    <h1>PNG:</h1>
  </header>
  <img id="svg-img" />
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying, how to do it on canvas objects. +1

Answer (score 1):

I'd "draw" the background in the svg with a `rect`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/gabelerner/canvg/master/canvg.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart" id="chart" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
  <!-- d3 code -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "mysvg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
    
    svg.append('rect')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)
      .style("fill", "red");
    
    svg.selectAll('.bar')
      .data([1,2,3,4])
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('y', function(d,i){
        return d * 50;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d,i){
        return 500 - (d * 50);
      })
      .attr('width', 50)
      .attr('x', function(d,i){
        return i * 100;
      })
      .style('fill', 'steelblue');
    
  </script>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), $('#chart').html());
    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    document.write('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: upvoted, its the same way i found out, 5 minutes before :D