# canvas toDataUrl() returning black image

Tags: canvas, canvg

I'm creating a canvas based on svg using canvg and then through canvas I'm downloading an image.

Here is the code for creating an canvas taking svg.

//Creating the canvas

```
var myCanvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
canvg(myCanvas, res[0],{ ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true , ignoreClear: true }); 



     //Downloading the image


 var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
           var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = name;
            link.href = uri;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
```

The image obtained is partially with black background.Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get background color of SVG converted properly into Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522927/how-to-get-background-color-of-svg-converted-properly-into-canvas)

Comment: Beside, converting an svg graphic to jpeg doesn't sound like a great idea, it obviously depends on the graphic, but most of the time png will offer a smaller output file size, with of course, better quality.

Comment: I found a problem and fixed it too.

I was converting svg to canvas taking svg element as a string, but some part of the svg has external css applied, due to which while taking markup from DOM I lost a css property and it result in partial black image.

Just added missed CSS as inline CSS and it solved the issue.

//a single line of code that fixed everything
$(".c3-chart-lines").find(".c3-line").css("fill", "none");

Thanks